# Finding the missing value while multiplying a percentage

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stumped on how to solve this:

```
y = (x*0.1)+2.7
```

So I'm trying to figure out what x must be for y to break even when 10% is added and an additional value, which is 2.7 here and could be substituted with z or something.

> **EDIT:**

I don't think I'm asking the question correctly, so let me try this as a word problem instead.

> I make a purchase for 2.70 and want to resale it and cover my cost. 
>   There's a fee of 10% of my selling price.  What I need to figure out is
>   what my minimal selling price must be in order for me to get my 2.70
>   back after selling the item.

I may have the formula wrong and please forgive me if so.

Comment: Put all the terms with $x$ on one side and everything else on the other side.

Comment: Thanks Ian, but that is where I'm stuck at.  I'm very rusty on my algebra and I'm not sure how to flip it and calculate it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to solve for $x$, then it's

$$
x = (y-2.7) / 0.1 = 10 ( y - 2.7).
$$

However, the textual description that "10% is added" makes me think that you want to solve $y = 1.1 x + 2.7$ instead, which would then be

$$
x = (y-2.7) / 1.1
$$

Hopefully that helps.

**Edit**:

- Let $x$ be the price for which you sell the item
- Let $f$ be the fraction of it you get to keep (so if there is a 10% fee, then you get to keep the other 90%, which would mean $f=0.90$)
- Let $y$ be what you originally paid for the item
- Let $p$ be the minimum amount of profit that you wish to make through the sale

Using the above symbols, we get the following relation for the value of $x$ that will give you the desired profit or more:

$$
 x \cdot f \ge y + p \Rightarrow x \ge (y + p ) / f
$$

For example, say you paid \$9.50 for a widget, that there is a 10% merchant's fee that must be paid, and that you require a profit of at least \$0.60 to make it worth your time. Then we get that you must price the widget at

$$
x \ge ( \$9.50 + \$0.60 ) / 0.9 = \$11.22222.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much +AnonSubmitter85!  That definitely helps clarify how to flip the problem and I really appreciate it.  I think I don't have my question correct, so I've edited it and given a written explanation of what I'm trying to solve for.

Comment: @Amereservant See if my update does not clear things up for you. Best of luck to you.